# arrayWithFile returns count of 0

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

I am writing an app that copies a plist into the docsdir and then reads it into a mutable array. The code below, however, returns a count of 0 for the array. The line with the dictionary log, however, returns the correct items. I have also verified that the file is being copied to the docsdir.

```
-(NSString *)docsDir {
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *listPath = [[self docsDir]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"list.plist"];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:listPath]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager]copyItemAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"list" ofType:@"plist"] toPath:listPath error:nil];
        NSLog(@"Chicken");
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:listPath]);
    _array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:listPath];

    NSLog(@"Count: %i", [_array count]);

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    / / Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this is because by default root element in plist files is a Dictionary.

Right click and select **Open as Source Code**, your file may look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>foo</key>
    <array>
        <string>foo1</string>
        <string>foo2</string>
        <string>foo3</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

where the root element is a dict, change it to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <string>foo1</string>
    <string>foo2</string>
    <string>foo3</string>
</array>
</plist>
```

where the root element is an array. You can now edit as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Open the plist file with Xcode.

Just find the 'key' at the top left corner and `Type` of the plist.

[image: Sample Plist file]

Make sure the `Type` is Array.

Answer (score 0):

I think your plist is a dictionary that contains an array.
Try this

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:listPath]
NSArray *array = [dict objectForKey:@"key"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Plists are usually saved a dictionaries:

Here's an example :

```
<dict>
    <key>tiltingAnim</key>
    <dict>
        <key>filenamePrefix</key>
        <string>radar_</string>
        <key>delay</key>
        <real>0.25</real>
        <key>animationFrames</key>
        <string>1,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,5</string>
    </dict>
    <key>takingAHitAnim</key>
    <dict>
        <key>filenamePrefix</key>
        <string>radar_</string>
        <key>delay</key>
        <real>0.1</real>
        <key>animationFrames</key>
        <string>5,5,7,8,8</string>
    </dict>
    <key>blowingUpAnim</key>
    <dict>
        <key>filenamePrefix</key>
        <string>radar_</string>
        <key>delay</key>
    <real>0.2</real>
    <key>animationFrames</key>
    <string>5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17</string>
    </dict>
    <key>transmittingAnim</key>
    <dict>
        <key>filenamePrefix</key>
        <string>radar_</string>
        <key>delay</key>
        <real>0.3</real>
        <key>animationFrames</key>
        <string>5,6,5,6,5,6,5</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Now, there are 2 solutions to your question.

1. Either get the contents into a dictionary then take out the array for a specific key.
2. Open up the plist with a text editor and change the root  key into  then change root  into . If your plist is static and in the bundle resources then you could do this but if it's a plist generated by your code then i wouldn't recommend this.